# How to pass parameters or values from report to another?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, mdx

I have designed  two  reports using  Microsoft Reporting Services and MDX queries to pull data from data analysis services. Now I want when I open  the first one and click on details it opens the second report and it should pass the two values to the parameters to the other report. These two parameters are month and year of a record click. I have tried but it is not working.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

We have two options in the case of passing parameters MDX to child report
1. construct the key of the values passing to child report
2. Pass the parameter values from parent to child

Both methods should work in SSRS reports using MDX.